# Would a group of creatures floating in Reverse Gravity have any chance at saving against a fireball?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw

I have a character with *reverse gravity* and *fireball* at their disposal. Would floating creatures affected by *reverse gravity* get a chance to make a dex save against *fireball* if they have no flying speed?

Answer (score 19):

**By RAW, the creatures affected by Reverse Gravity who are targeted by a Fireball would still get a Dexterity saving throw.** There is nothing in the spell's descriptions that would suggest otherwise.

If the creature does not strike any objects or a ceiling on the way upwards then, like it says in the spell, it will remain there "oscillating slightly, for the duration" or floating as you mentioned.

The spell does not cause a creature to be Paralyzed or Stunned (*Player's Handbook*, pp. 291-292). If a creature is Paralyzed or Stunned they are  Incapacitated (cannot take actions or reactions), cannot move or speak, and the creature fails any Strength and Dexterity saving throws. The spell also does not say the creatures are Incapacitated either (*Player's Handbook*, p.291) so they can use actions and reactions.

As a DM, in this case, I would still allow a Dexterity saving throw at my table, with disadvantage because of the logical difficulty in being dexterous while "floating" - but that is not RAW and every DM will have a concept of what is logical or not whilst remembering it is a fantasy setting. I would not remove the saving throw altogether because PCs may have weird and wonderful ways of wriggling out of a danger.
If the player could describe how their PC intends to make a Dexterity saving throw, I would allow a regular Dexterity saving throw, e.g. they push off another floating object, swiftly grab an object to cover themselves, twist their body to miss some of the flames, curling up to self-protect and avoid damage to their face or hands, etc. This might add a nice visual narrative to the encounter, too.

Comment: As an argument for always allowing a regular saving throw in this case (the RAW), making a Dex save against a fireball doesn't necessarily mean you got out of the way or ducked behind someone else - after all a creature standing alone in an empty chamber has no disadvantage.  It's more about reacting to cover up your more vital bits. For someone floating in the air this would be about protecting your face, hands, and other bits of exposed skin when the fireball explodes; likely by curling into a ball or at least raising your arms to your face and turning away.

Comment: @RisingZan Thank you. That makes a lot of sense. I'll incorporate your point into the answer.

Comment: In further support of @RisingZan's argument, note that even a rogue with Evasion doesn't leave their space even when taking no damage after a successful save against Meteor Swarm centred on them (40 ft radius).  If avoiding or reducing damage required you to get out of the area, you'd be somewhere else.  That's part of why it's *half* damage for normal characters, not zero, on a success.  (Rogues maybe are better at ducking and covering, or are assumed to have special clothes to help, or whatever narrative justification fits the rogue.  Or it just kind of gets hand-waved for Meteor Swarm.)

Comment: @RisingZan: And of course, grabbing the edge of one's cloak to swiftly interpose it between yourself and the onrushing flames! (Which makes a lot more sense for Fireball than Meteor Swarm)

Comment: If you can think of a way a PC could avoid the blast, you should just not give disadvantage to any PC. One _character_ should not take more damage than another because the other _player_ is better at lateral thinking.

Comment: Way back in 3.5 something very similar to this came up. My players were big into describing their saves and the player said" I huck my warhammer, using newton's law to push me {in the opposite direction}, so I can avoid the ray" I was so impressed I had to award bonus xp at the end of the encounter.

Answer (score 9):

### Yes

The rules as written which are relevant to this situation don't deny creatures the ability to make dexterity saves. The text of the spell doesn't state that floating creatures cannot make such saves, nor does it impose any conditions on affected creatures that would have that consequence.

Without the ability to fly, they can't effect significant movement while they're floating up there, but then the ability to move far has never been a requirement for dodging fireballs anyway - even on the ground, a successful dexterity save wouldn't have made them move from the five foot space they were already in. While floating, they can still contort and twist themselves in such a way as to try and avoid the worst of an effect such as fireball.

Your DM would be free to make alternative rulings if they chose, though. Personally, I might be persuaded to rule that being stuck at the top of the gravity well without the ability to fly is similar enough to being [restrained](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Restrained), which would cause disadvantage on dexterity saves.